# stack smashing detected comes in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, ubuntu-16.04

Earlier in Ubuntu 14.04, I used compile a code (using gcc) and no such error used to come. But when I upgrade to 16.04, the same code is giving me this error:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./main terminated
Aborted (core dumped).
```

Why is so? When I used  `-fno-stack-protector` while compiling the error vanished (no segmentation fault either).

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question?

Comment: Earlier in 14.04, I did not have to use  -fno-stack-protector. But now I have to. Why? * stack smashing detected * is not something new that it comes with 16.04 upgrade.

Comment: I suggest you actually read what `-fno-stack-protector` _actually does_. I suggest you go learn how to open your program in a debugger.

Comment: In gcc version: 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3), stack smashing detected does not come. But when I use gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609, this error comes. My question is, can I go back to a gcc version in ehich this does not come?

Comment: Why don't you fix your code instead of trying to find a compiler option to ignore the error? That error is serious and should not be ignored (unless you are deliberately corrupting memory for some purpose).

Comment: Actually, my code requires huge memory. So I need to use: ulimit -s unlimited. With this, the gcc did not give this stack smashing error earlier (14.04). But with the upgrade in gcc, this error comes. Can I avoid it now. I can not change the code, it is optimised professionally.

Answer (score 1):

Stack protector in Ubuntu 16's GCC 4.9 became [more aggressive](https://wiki.debian.org/Hardening#DEB_BUILD_HARDENING_STACKPROTECTOR_.28gcc.2Fg.2B-.2B-_-fstack-protector-strong.29) so it likely to detect hidden bug in your code.